# How can I call a plugin function from WordPress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to call a function located in the plugin directories, but couldn't.
in plugins/quipinvoices/include/payments.php :

```
if (!class_exists('QuipInvoicesPayment'))
{
class QuipInvoicesPayment extends QuipInvoicesController
{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
// some hooks here
}

public function create_manual_payment()
{
// function content here
}
}
}
```

I'm trying to call the function create_manual_payment() from the theme template. But it say Call to undefined function.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the plugin is loaded, you should be able to use:

```
$payment = new QuipInvoicesPayment();
// Call the method
$payment->create_manual_payment();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function create_manual_payment() on a non-object

Comment: Then it sounds like your plugin isn't loaded at that point in time

Comment: it is activated. is that what loaded mean ?

Comment: where should I put those 2 lines ? both in plugins/quipinvoices/include/payments.php or in the theme template ?